# Apache Camel get Thread pool queue size

Tags: apache-camel

I have Thread pool profile like below:

```
<threadPoolProfile id="myThrottler"
                           poolSize="5"
                           maxPoolSize="20"
                           maxQueueSize="1000"
                           rejectedPolicy="CallerRuns"/>
```

I'm using this thread pool in route:

```
 <route>
      <from uri="stream:in"/>
      <throttle timePeriodMillis="2000" asyncDelayed="true" executorServiceRef="myThrottler">
                <constant>5</constant>
            </throttle>
            <log message="${threadName}"/>
        </route>
```

I can get thread name by `<log message="${threadName}"/>`

Can I get the queue size using in thread pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the thread pool queue size from the `<log>` which uses the Simple language.

But you can use JMX to get metrics from the thread pool, such as the queue size etc.

- http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html